# Getting the number of different values in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to know the number of *different* values in an array. For example if it contains (5, 5, 5) then I should get 1. If it contains (4, 4, 2, 2) I should get 2. If (5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5) then 3.

Is there a function that can achieve that directly in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo count(array_unique($arr));`

you can use `array_unique` which returns unique elements of array (result is also array type) and then `count` on result

Answer (score 1):

Two simple ways to achieve that:

- `$diff_count = count(array_unique($input_arr));`
- `$diff_count = count(array_flip($input_arr));` <-- recommended (performance)

**array_unique()** :

Removes duplicate values from an array - you can add adittional flags such as:

- SORT_REGULAR - compare items normally (don't change types)
- SORT_NUMERIC - compare items numerically
- SORT_STRING - compare items as strings
- SORT_LOCALE_STRING - compare items as strings, based on the current locale.

**array_flip()**:

Exchanges all keys with their associated values in an array - so duplicates keys are overwritten and you get a final array with the unique values as keys.

Flipping it twice will result in an array with unique values and the highest keys there were in the original input array.

**More reading**:

- [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).
- [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php).

**Benchmark**:

Since the array_flip uses only O(n) exactly its much faster - using an array of 10,000 numbers as an input:

- array_unique + count: ~28.615 ms.
- array_flip + count:   ~0.5012 ms. (**winner**)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a function that can achieve that directly in PHP?

The closest one would be `array_unique()` but here is a simple function to achieve what you are looking for:

```
$arr = array(5,5,5,5,2,2,1,5);

function array_diff_values( $array ) {
    return count( array_unique($array) );
}

$count = array_diff_values( $arr );
```

result of `$count` is `3`